# A short c++ file and makefile: I can make in the shell, but get lots of error while building it in the Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I'm compiling a very short c++ file using makefile.The c++ file using a external libary named ClanLib, but that's not the point, because I can use "make" command to  compile it in the shell, so the c++ file and the makefile are OK.

```
#include <ClanLib/core.h>
#include <ClanLib/application.h>

class ConsoleProgram {
public:
    static int main(const std::vector<CL_String> &args);
};
CL_ClanApplication app(&ConsoleProgram::main);
int ConsoleProgram::main(const std::vector<CL_String> &args) {
    CL_SetupCore setup_core;
    CL_ConsoleWindow console_window("Console");
    CL_Console::write_line("Hello World!");
    CL_Console::wait_for_key();
    return 0;
}




BIN     = main
OBJF    = main.o
LIBS    = clanCore  clanDisplay  clanGL  clanGL1  clanApp clanSWRender
VERSION = 2.3

PACKAGES = $(patsubst %, %-$(VERSION), $(LIBS))
INCLUDE += -I/usr/include/ClanLib-2.3/ 
CXXFLAGS += $(INCLUDE) `pkg-config --cflags $(PACKAGES)` -pthread

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJF)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJF) -o $(BIN) `pkg-config --libs $(PACKAGES)`

clean:
    find . -name '*.o' -type f -print -exec rm -rf {} \;
    rm -f $(BIN)

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.o : %.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

But I get lots of errors while compiling it in the eclipse, I've been googling from morning but without any clues.

```
/usr/include/ClanLib-2.3/ClanLib/Core/Crypto/aes128_decrypt.h:116:2: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/include/ClanLib-2.3/ClanLib/core.h:217:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/ClanLib-2.3/ClanLib/Core/Crypto/aes192_encrypt.h:114:2: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/include/ClanLib-2.3/ClanLib/core.h:218:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/ClanLib-2.3/ClanLib/Core/Crypto/aes192_decrypt.h:116:2: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/include/ClanLib-2.3/ClanLib/core.h:219:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/ClanLib-2.3/ClanLib/Core/Crypto/aes256_encrypt.h:114:2: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/include/ClanLib-2.3/ClanLib/core.h:220:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/ClanLib-2.3/ClanLib/Core/Crypto/aes256_decrypt.h:116:2: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Any clue or advise will be very appreciated.

I'm useing Fedora 17 x86_64, eclipse indigo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `std=c++0x` to the g++ compiler flags to get `std::shared_ptr`.